# Awesomium not loading page or triggering any events

Tags: c#, awesomium

I want to do something a simple as loading a webpage. For some reason Awesomium is not updating properties such as IsLoading, or triggering events such as DocumentReady or LoadingFrameComplete and I have no idea why, can anyone help me out?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Awesomium.Core;

namespace DownloaderTest
{
    class ParsingHelper
    {
        WebView wv;

        public ParsingHelper(WebView web)
        {
            this.wv = web;
        }

        public void ParsingInitiation(string link)
        {
            wv.LoadingFrameComplete +=wv_LoadingFrameComplete;

            wv.Source = new Uri(link);
        }

        void wv_LoadingFrameComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.IsMainFrame)
            {
                //BeginParsing
                ((WebView)sender).LoadingFrameComplete -= wv_LoadingFrameComplete;
            }

        }
    }

    class Teste
    {
        WebView MainWeb = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024,768);

        public object[] ObtainInformation(int id)
        {
            ParsingHelper ph = new ParsingHelper(MainWeb);

            ph.ParsingInitiation("http://www.google.com");

            //More code

            return new object[] {};
        }


    }
}
```

If I run something like...

```
Teste t = new Teste();
t.ObtainInformation(1);
```

`wv_LoadingFrameComplete` is never triggered and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

try this code to detect page loaded completely
loadingFrameCompete event + IsLoading property

```
private void Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_LoadingFrameComplete(object sender, Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!webControl1.IsLoading)
                MessageBox.Show("Page Loaded Completely");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/2260/awesomium-not-loading-page-or-triggering-any-event.html

You are either using Awesomium in non UI environment (not WPF/WinForms control) and must call WebCore.Update() implicitly or you just blocking the same thread so it can't fire events.

Comment: The `WebCore.Update()` method is now deprecated since the `WebCore.Run()` already updates when there are updates to handle.

Comment: @JonathanPerry iirc it still may be needed in some cases. Though isn't the whole Awesomium is now "deprecated"?:) Looks like it didn't have updates for 3 years and even their forum is closed.

Comment: According to their website it's still going strong, I myself am looking for alternatives to PhantomJS and stumbled upon this library.

Comment: @JonathanPerry According to what? Last update was 3 years ago and they did not fulfilled most of their 4-5 years old promises like new Chromium version, x64, fixing bugs, etc. Anyway since you mentioned PhantomJS then I guess you are interested in some kind of automation, not HTML UI. So Awesomium is probably not the right tool for that. since it was designed for other goals + it uses ancient Chromium version, many modern websites do not work well in it. I would choose Selenium (it has WebDrivers for many browsers, including PhantomJS).

Comment: I actually just want to save a portion of the web page as an image on the server. PhantomJS does this well with their WebServer module, but since it's marked as "Experimental", I don't want to use it in production.